# Displaying values from a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

Right now, this block of code displays all five ice cream flavors. I'm trying to display only the flavors that are in stock.

```
   <pre><?php

   $flavors = array();
   $flavors[] = array("name" => "Cookie Dough",      "in_stock" => true);
   $flavors[] = array("name" => "Vanilla",           "in_stock" => false);
   $flavors[] = array("name" => "Avocado Chocolate", "in_stock" => false);
   $flavors[] = array("name" => "Bacon Me Crazy",    "in_stock" => true);
   $flavors[] = array("name" => "Strawberry",        "in_stock" => false);

   foreach($flavors as $flavor) {


    echo $flavor["name"] . "\n";


  }

  ?></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

```
foreach($flavors as $flavor) {
   if($flavor['in_stock'] === true)
       echo $flavor["name"] . "\n";
}
```

Comment: the ` === true` is not necessary in this case.

Comment: @BadHorsie: Yes that is right. But i think writing a little bit more code to help an beginner understand isn't bad at all :)

Answer (score 0):

You can still use foreach loop, but check for the stock using the `if` statement

```
foreach($flavors as $flavor) {
  if ($flavor["in_stock"])
    echo $flavor["name"] . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
echo $flavor["name"] . "\n";
```

with

```
if ($flavor['in_stock']) {
  echo $flavor["name"] . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($flavors as $flavor)
{
   if ($flavor['in_stock'])
   {
       echo $flavor["name"] . "\n";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$flavorsInStock = array_filter($flavors, function($flavor) {
    return $flavor['in_stock'];
});
```

Will give you a new array with just the flavors that are in stock.